# ios swift - instantiating same VC from multiple tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have multiple tabs connected via separate navigation controllers. I want to to instantiate same End Pt VC, irrespective of which tab user chooses tabs 1 through 4.

[image: storyboard]

When I select Tab 1 it shows End Pt VC because it is connected via Segue. However when I select other tabs I manually try to push EndPt VC as shown in the tab controller method. But it shows blank screen. How can I present the same End Pt VC irrespective of tab selection?

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EndPointTVC") as? EndPtListTableViewController{
        viewController.selectedTab = self.selectedTab

        if let navigator = self.navigationController {
            navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect when the `UITabBarController` changes tab via its delegate `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. In the following delegate method, you can cast the selected view controller to a `UINavigationController` (which is what I can make out in the screenshot you attached).

```
extension MyTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let myVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewControllerStoryID") as! MyViewController
        let navController = viewController as! UINavigationController
        navController.viewControllers = [myVC]
        print(viewController)
    }
}
```

Now, no matter which tab you choose, a new `MyViewController` instance is created. Even hitting the same tab multiple times will replace the current instance for a new `MyViewController` instance.

Comment: I added the extension method you provided to my TabBarController class, it shows black screen when I select Tabs 2,3,4. Tab 1 works because End Pt VC is connected to Tab 1 via navigation controller. I put in a debug inside the extension method.  Looks like the extension is never called. How to make sure it gets called?

Comment: my mistake, I forgot to assign the delegate to tabbar controller as  self.delegate = self.. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to instantiate the viewcontroller from the storyboard and then present it. Also, make sure that you have given the target viewcontroller the storyboard Id "EndPointTVC" in the Identify section.

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier : "EndPointTVC")
    viewController.selectedTab = self.selectedTab
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: I understand first parameter storyboadName : String refers to EndPt VC storyboard ID. Which is the second parameter vc:UIViewController  your are referring to? I don't understand where it is coming from?

Comment: Also EndPt is a UITableViewController. Sorry I mentioned it as ViewController